# How to remove empty paragraph tags from string?

Tags: php

I ran into a slight coding problem with WordPress template. This is the code I use in template:

```
<?php echo teaser(40); ?>
```

In my functions, I use this to strip tags and get content from allowed tags only.

```
<?php
function teaser($limit) {
    $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
    if (count($content)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($content);
    $content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
    } else {
    $content = implode(" ",$content);
    }   
    $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    $content = strip_tags($content, '<p><a><ul><li><i><em><strong>');
    return $content;
}
?>
```

The problem: I use the above code to strip  tags from the content, but WordPress already puts image tags within paragraph. So the result is empty paragraph tags where images are stripped.

Just for the sake of cleaning up my code and useless empty tags.
My question is how to remove empty paragraph tags?

```
<p></p>
```

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

use this regex to remove empty paragraph

```
/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/
```

example

```
<?php
$html = "abc<p></p><p>dd</p><b>non-empty</b>"; 
$pattern = "/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/"; 
//$pattern = "/<[^\/>]*>([\s]?)*<\/[^>]*>/";  use this pattern to remove any empty tag

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $html); 
// output
//abc<p>dd</p><b>non-empty</b>
?>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Looks more complicated than str_replace solution posted here.. any technical difference?

Comment: regex is always best practice, "<p > </p>" str_replace cant replace these type where as regex does.

Comment: everyone does this "anything but" approach, and I never understood why.. essentially what you're trying to do is match *everything* until the next `>`, i.e., an *ungreedy* search... so why not make it ungreedy and maintain readability? `<p(\s.*?)?>` or is there something wrong with that that i'm overlooking? ps: your thing matches `<pooptag></poopface>`. I also don't understand why people are so damn insistent on using `/` for the start/end character and then forcing themselves to escape them all... WHY?!?! use a freaking backtick or a character that *isn't* in your pattern.

Comment: also, don't tell him "regex is always best practice", it most certainly is not!!! regexes are *generally* awful at parsing HTML. this particular example is simple enough that a regex can handle it, but you shouldn't be recommending it as a one-size-fits-all. the *real* reason for using a regex here is that it's more flexible.. it will strip `p` tags that have attributes too.

Comment: str_replace is for string replace , where as requirement is pattern match.

Comment: This regex stripped empty p tags even if it has class.. i think thats more suitable now, but whats the pooptag thing? .. I do not get it, does this snippet have exceptions?

Comment: don't try to remove all empty tags as something like font-awesome's use of `<i>` would get removed eg `<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>`

Answer (score 45):

This gets rid of all empty `p` tags, even if they contain `spaces` or `&nbps;` inside.

```
$str = "<p>  </p><p> &nbsp; </p><p>&nbsp</p><p>Sample Text</p>";

echo preg_replace("/<p[^>]*>(?:\s|&nbsp;)*<\/p>/", '', $str);
```

This only echoes `<p>Sample Text</p>`

Comment: That's what I need , thank you
I think I don't need to add "\t" for getting red tabs, right?

Comment: This will not work properly, due to how `[]` works in regex it will even match paragraphs like `<p>ps; spnnnn pppp bbb &bs;</p>` which is surely not empty. It could be fixed to `/<p[^>]*>([\s]|&nbsp;)*<\/p>/` though

Comment: This does not work; see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8f52f2fcb1b87a3af3f947c74d85c346e38f8c0 for an example of an "empty" <p> tag that is not stripped.

Answer (score 7):

This function remove empty elements and then, other empty elements, created from previous removed elements. (The example string contains spaces, tabs and carriage returns.)

```
function teaser( $html ) {
    $html = str_replace( '&nbsp;', ' ', $html );
    do {
        $tmp = $html;
        $html = preg_replace(
            '#<([^ >]+)[^>]*>[[:space:]]*</\1>#', '', $html );
    } while ( $html !== $tmp );

    return $html;
}
```

Having the following example:

```
<?php

    $html = '
    <p>Hello!
        <div class="foo">
            <p id="nobody">
                <span src="ok">&nbsp;</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </p>
    ';

echo teaser( $html );

?>
```

The function returns:

```
<p>Hello!

</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use str_replace to remove empty `<p></p>` tags.

```
$content = str_replace("<p></p>","",$content);
```

Anything more advanced will need regular expressions.

Comment: I'm not sure how WordPress generates tags, but if you had an input like this, it would not be matched: `<p class="bla"></p>`

Answer (score 3):

```
$content = preg_replace('/<p[^>]*?></p>/', $content);
```

Update: should be:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<p [^>]*></p>/', $content);
```

Comment: why did you make it match anything *but* `>` *and* make it ungreedy? isn't that redundant? also, it will match any tag that starts with a `p`; `<pre></p>`, not that it's valid html, but you might as well get it right.

Comment: Good catch on both. I generally default to ungreedy matches, because it's so easy to  accidentally slip in a greedy match that destroys the pattern, but in this case it is unnecessary.

Answer (score -6):

Remove the `<p>` tag from your strip_tags call.  The second argument lists the acceptable tags (that don't get stripped).

```
$content = strip_tags($content, '<a><ul><li><i><em><strong>');
```

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention that <p> paragraph has to be an allowed tag. For the purpose of formatting. The only thing I want to do is, clean up empty paragraph tags.

Answer (score -6):

Have you tried the CSS3 solution?

```
p:empty {display: none;}
```

Comment: alongside a relevant answer this is also a good workaround.

Comment: I guess this got downvoted cos it's not PHP and don't actually remove the tags - But it's a good solution :-)