# Using regex to remove empty paragraph tags <p> </p> (standard str_replace on "space" not working)

Tags: php, regex, tinymce

TinyMCE creates empty paragraph tags when you hit enter twice. like:

```
<p> </p>
```

Which is 
`<p>SPACE</p>`

In FireBug it calls this space a `"&nbsp;"` but the html code/DB backend just shows a space. When I do `"str_replace('<p> </p>'....."` it doesnt find the block... basically I think the "space" is somehow not a standard space and some sort of borked encoded space. Is there a regex I can run that will remove this tag? I've been stuck on this for hours... or even something like

`regex('<p>LESS THAN THREE CHARS</p>'...)`

would probably work

Thank you

Comment: `regex('<p>.</p>'...)`   a period may work for this character?

Comment: Non-breaking space does have a different code point. Can you loop through the string and check print the numeric equivalent of the character?

Comment: Ok, when I do utf8_encode(<p> </p>) I am getting <p>Â </p>...turns out the DB was ISO, but now has been changed to UTF8 encoding... so now how do I get rid of this garbage data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove empty paragraph tags from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809108/how-to-remove-empty-paragraph-tags-from-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use:

```
$str = preg_replace('~<p>\s*<\/p>~i','',$str);
```

where `\s` signifies a white space of any kind (tab, space, etc.) and `*` indicates 0 or more occurence of this (space). So `<p></p>`, `<p> </p>`, `<p>{multiple spaces here}</p>` will all be replaced by an empty string. The additional `i` flag is for case-insensitivity, just in case `<p>`'s might instead be `<P>`'s.

Comment: no dice... Warning: preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: @inhan There is no g flag, that is only for str_replace(). preg_replace automatically replaces everything from the input. Chad, remove the g flag and it should work.

Comment: Sorry confused Javascript and PHP flags :) Editing my post. Thanks @TurdPile

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = preg_replace('#<p>&nbsp;</p>#i','<p></p>', $text);
```

worked for me, as the variable contains the actual string `"&nbsp;"` and not the non-breaking space unicode character. Thus neither `#<p>.</p>#i` worked nor copying the non-breaking-space character from character map.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above won't work if `<p>` tag has any inline attributes, such as 
`<p style="font-weight:bold">`.

Here is a regex to catch it:

```
#<p[^>]*>(\s|&nbsp;|</?\s?br\s?/?>)*</?p>#
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the given answers were working for me, but here's what did:

```
$str = str_replace('&lt;p&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;', '', $str);
```

Definitely not the most correct way to do things. But if you're working with (against) TinyMCE, specifically inside of SuiteCRM, this should help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$string="a bunch of text with <p> </p> in it";

$string=str_replace("/<p> <\/p>/","",$string);
```

Note a couple things: the forward slashes before and after the string to match, as well as the escaping backslash before the forward slash in the second paragraph tag.

Comment: This is a poor example for this. Using regular expressions with preg_replace is the way to go.

Comment: @TurdPile I didn't say it was a good example, but the OP's question was regarding the regex method, not the merits of str_replace. I personally use preg_replace as well.

Comment: Problem is you missed two big features that would make that work, one is you should be using \s+ instead of a space, secondly, you should use the g flag to signify a global replacement, otherwise it will simply replace the first one it comes across.