# Removing "blank" paragraph tags from TinyMCE

Tags: php, tinymce, tinymce-4

This is the same issue as was asked here in 2012, which was not answered:

[Using regex to remove empty paragraph tags <p> </p> (standard str_replace on "space" not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572183/using-regex-to-remove-empty-paragraph-tags-p-p-standard-str-replace-on-sp)

When I press enter in TINYMCE, it appears to enter empty paragraph tags like this:

```
<p> </p>
```

I wanted to remove them before saving the data to a MySQL table.

So I tried a simple fix:

```
$post_content = str_replace('<p> </p>', '', $content_from_mce);
```

And also:

```
$post_content = str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p>', '', $content_from_mce);
```

However, they do not work (e.g. the don't replace the apparently empty paragraph tags).

If I do this:

```
$foo = utf8_encode($post_content);
```

And then check $foo: it shows as:

```
<p>Â </p>
```

So really it's not an empty paragraph tag, but I can't work out how to delete these blocks of text.

I've also tried these versions (not all at the same time - I mean in different runs...)

```
$post_content = str_replace('<p>Â </p>','',$post_content);
$post_content = preg_replace('~<p>\s*<\/p>~i','',$post_content);
$post_content = preg_replace('#<p>&nbsp;</p>#i','<p></p>', $post_content);
$post_content=str_replace("/<p> <\/p>/","",$post_content);
```

But none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - I'm using [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to make sure the posted content from TinyMCE is okay.

After the $post_content has been through HTMLPurifier it contains that funny character between the paragraph tags.

Therefore if I do the replace before putting $post_content through HTMLPurifier it works okay:

```
$config =   HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

// get contents of "post_content" field
$post_content = $_POST['post_content'];

// remove blank paragraph lines
$post_content = str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p>','',$post_content);

// now put $post_content through HTMLPurifier 
$post_content = $purifier->purify($post_content);
```