# PHP RegEx remove empty paragraph tags

Tags: php, regex, ckeditor

I'm trying to remove all empty `<p>` tags CKEditor is inserting in to a description box but they all seem to vary. The possibilities seem to be:

```
<p></p>

<p>(WHITESPACE)</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><br /></p>

<p>(NEWLINE)&nbsp;</p>

<p>(NEWLINE)<br /><br />(NEWLINE)&nbsp;</p>
```

With these possibilities, there could be any amount of whitespace, `&nbsp;` and `<br />` tags in between the paragraphs, and there could be some of each kind in one paragraph.

I'm also not sure about the `<br />` tag, from what I've seen it could be `<br />`, `<br/>` or `<br>`.

I've searched SO for a similar answer but of all the answers I've seen they all seem to cater for just one of these cases, not all at once. I guess in simple terms what I'm asking is, Is there a regular expression I can use to remove all `<p>` tags from some HTML that don't have any alphanumeric text or symbols/punctuation in them?

Comment: And this is why you don't [Parse HTML with Regexes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Comment: So you really think I should use an HTML parser for a string such as '<p>Text</p><p>&nbsp;</p>' - Seems like overkill don't you think?

Comment: This isn't parsing, techincally.  And if the desired effect is suitably narrow (i.e. if you expect no understanding, just pattern matching), there's nothing wrong with Regexing a string.  Cthulu will stay in his box.

Comment: I'm curious as to why @AndyLester thinks using DOMDocument to parse a 24 character HTML string is a good idea

Comment: Like I said, "as soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken."  If you have a single HTML document that lives on your machine and it won't change, then go ahead and regex it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove empty paragraph tags from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809108/how-to-remove-empty-paragraph-tags-from-string)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, in conflict with my suggestion not to parse HTML with regexes, I wrote up a regex to do just that:

```
"#<p>(\s|&nbsp;|</?\s?br\s?/?>)*</?p>#"
```

This will match properly for:

```
<p></p>

<p> </p> <!-- ([space]) -->

<p> </p> <!-- (That's a [tab] character in there -->

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><br /></p>

<p>
&nbsp;</p>

<p>
<br /><br />
&nbsp;</p>
```

What it does:

```
# /                --> Regex start
# <p>              --> match the opening <p> tag
# (                --> group open.
#   \s             --> match any whitespace character (newline, space, tab)
# |                --> or
#   &nbsp;         --> match &nbsp;
# |                --> or
#   </?\s?br\s?/?> --> match the <br> tag
# )*               --> group close, match any number of any of the elements in the group
# </?p>            --> match the closing </p> tag ("/" optional)
# /                --> regex end.
```

Comment: Two things:  use a different deilimiter, your regex will break like crazy because you forgot to escape the forwardslashes.  Additionally, the examples in the post don't seem to have terminating tags.  I wrote the regex slightly differently: `#<p>(\s+|&nbsp;|<br\s*/?>)*(</p>)(?=<p>)#`  Of course, you can pepper in `\s*` for all sorts of whitespace concerns.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: the examples in the posts seem to use `<p>` as terminating tags. I'll make the `/` in `</p>` optional.Other than that, thanks for the suggestions. I made such a "mess" of the `<br>` to catch all "possibilities" I've seen used.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did't work with the / as the delimiter but worked perfectly once changed to #

Comment: Ah, tagged php. Was used to the JS syntax, but somehow I forgot to escape the `/`'s in there -.-
Thanks for accepting my answer!

Comment: @Cerbrus Apologies for the confusion. For some reason I had to use &lt; and &gt; to get the tags showing correctly so missed out the / on the </p>'s

Comment: @Cerbrus I forgot all about code blocks, how stupid of me. Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer is great, but it doesn't work if `<p>` tag has inline style attributes defined, like `<p style="font-weight:bold">`.

A regex to match this, would be:

```
#<p[^>]*>(\s|&nbsp;|</?\s?br\s?/?>)*</?p>#
```

Comment: Good answer, I just tried this with all the test cases in my original question plus `<p style="text-align:left"></p>` and it works well