# Stuck Inside Blockquote In TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to embed a tweet in TinyMCE's WYSIWYG. When I place the content on the page, the html looks like this:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p>Equally Armed !!! AR-15, the Modern Musket <a href="http://t.co/GnuhTTkQML">pic.twitter.com/GnuhTTkQML</a></p>&mdash; John Sykes (@johnsykes1035) <a href="https://twitter.com/johnsykes1035/statuses/452098680607490048">April 4, 2014</a></blockquote>
```

So the content is within the blockquote tag.

NOW - if this is the ONLY entry on the page, when I come back to re-edit, I get stuck inside the blockquote, no matter where I place the cursor or how many enter I press, it never escapes the blockquote.

Same problem is the tweet is the first thing on the page and then I write text... I cannot go ABOVE the tweet to insert text because if I place my cursor above it and press enter, I'm still inside the blockquote. If the tweet is at the bottom, then it doesn't matter that I put the cursor at the end of the text and hit enter, I'm still inside the blockquote tags.

I've even tried wrapping it an div like so:

```
<div><blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p>Equally Armed !!! AR-15, the Modern Musket <a href="http://t.co/GnuhTTkQML">pic.twitter.com/GnuhTTkQML</a></p>&mdash; John Sykes (@johnsykes1035) <a href="https://twitter.com/johnsykes1035/statuses/452098680607490048">April 4, 2014</a></blockquote></div>
```

But then it just stays trapped inside the div.

So HOW exactly would one be able to escape the blockquote when you re-initialize tinyMCE with this content for editing?

I need client friendly solution.

Thank you

Comment: Golly you're right! Here's a fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Baeaab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit enter a few times, then choose `paragraph` Format.

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67589325/blockquote.png]

---

**edit** More correctly, you should not choose `paragraph` format, but unselect the `blockquote` format. For the case when the cursor is above the blockquote, deselecting `blockquote` format is a solution.

---

Here is a solution that, although technically suboptimal, it does the trick.

Initialize your editor with the value:

```
<p></p><blockquote>tweet tweet tweet</blockquote><p></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This has a few problems though. 1) It doesn't work to put a paragraph above (it keeps inserting p inside blockquote) 2) it's not client friendly... most people know that clicking enter gets them a new paragraph - they have no idea what blockquote and divs are and how to use them. I guess I should have added that to my op - I need client friendly solution.

Comment: Ah, I thought this was for your own use. I need to go to my actual job in a few minutes.

Comment: :) If it was just me I'd do it in html directly and save myself the headache. Thank you though.

Comment: ok there's a dirty solution. Probably not great but it does the job. you could always remove a heading/trailing `<p></p>` afterward if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually trying that right now. I just have to find a reliable way of deleting the p tags in php. str_replace doesn't work properly and the other solutions from this link are not working either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809108/how-to-remove-empty-paragraph-tags-from-string

Comment: How about adding/removing in javascript when the editor is blurred/focused?

Comment: I took them out in php. It was a bit of a hassle but it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869608/unrecognized-character-between-empty-p-tags-tinymce/22869778?noredirect=1#comment34893813_22869778

Comment: That was a neat solution.

Comment: With the elegance of a bull in a china shop... but it works :) -Thank you