# Unrecognized Character Between Empty P Tags TinyMCE

Tags: regex, tinymce, preg-replace, str-replace, tinymce-4

What character does tinyMCE put in between empty p tags.

I have the following empty p tags:

```
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
```

Which I'd like to remove... but they are not recognized by str_replace or preg_replace. The best I could do to track down the issue, is the **space** between the tags. In other words I can remove the

```
<p>
```

by itself or the

```
</p>
```

... but when I try searching for

```
<p> </p>
```

it doesn't find it.

Tried

```
&nbsp;
```

or

```
&#32;
```

I found many solutions online but NONE work. It seems the character in question (the space between the p tags) is different or somehow not recognized. I say this because I tried the following

```
str_replace(" ", "", $html);
```

All of the other spaces in the string got deleted... **EXCEPT** for the space between the p tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably some non-printing unicode character of some type.  `\s` or maybe `\pS`.

```
preg_replace("@<p>[\pZ\pC]*</p>@u", "", $string);
```

Comment: Thanks - tried it - did not work. P tags still present.

Comment: @NoodleHead try actually copying one of those characters from your input string and pasting it into `str_replace` argument or something

Comment: @NoodleHead could it also be that you're just doing `preg_replace($r, $repl, $string)` and not `$string = preg_replace($r, $repl, $string)`?

Comment: @Explossion Pills My code: $html = preg_replace ("@<p>\pS*</p>@", "", $html);

Comment: @NoodleHead what about `[\pS\\n]*`?

Comment: $html = preg_replace ("@<p>[\pS\\n]*</p>@", "", $html); - P tags still there and unrecognized.

Comment: @NoodleHead did you try the copy and paste thing I suggested?

Comment: That was my first debugging attempt, copying the characters directly from there and pasting in my code. No result.

Comment: There's something about that space that it just does not recognize. everything around it can be easily manipulated.

Comment: @NoodleHead try `@<p>[\pZ\pC]*</p>@u`

Comment: That did IT - add it/edit the solution please - and explain it a bit for me and others looking for this. Thanks :)