# Remove empty html tags with PHP

Tags: php, html, tags

I am receiving a piece of HTML code which I insert in my database. 
However when an HTML tag is empty like

```
<p></p>
```

A strange character is stored in the database and then shown in the page.

I want to keep the rest of the html tags.

I think the best idea would be regex but I am not very good at it.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809108/how-to-remove-empty-paragraph-tags-from-string

Comment: You don't use regexes on html, ESPECIALLY when you are "not very good at it". Use a proper html cleanup tool, like HTMLPurifier.

Comment: @MarcB - what you say makes sense - can you explain why / what the consequences are?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Regex):

```
echo preg_replace('/<p>\s?<\/p>/', '', $yourString);
```

http://www.regexr.com/38s9s

Note: Couldn't tested with php.