# Removing empty <p> tags from the start of the string and last of the string containing html in PHP

Tags: php

I have a html string in the format like

```
<p><br /></p><p><br /></p><p>some random stuf</p><p><br /></p><p><br /></p>
```

Now i need to remove the

```html
<p>
```

tags that contains only

```html
<br />
```

element in the start of the string as well as on the tail side of the string in PHP.
How can i remove?

Comment: you can simply use `str_replace('<p><br /></p>',"",$str);` using php.

Comment: @Rits: what if string contains some other tags ?

Comment: its a 100% duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809108/how-to-remove-empty-paragraph-tags-from-string) .

Comment: so your have to make pattern and use preg replace, might be preg replace can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove empty paragraph tags from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809108/how-to-remove-empty-paragraph-tags-from-string)

Comment: usign str_replace() replaces every occurrence of the string even in the middle ??

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by few steps:

- Explode by each `<p>` tag
- Traverse all element via `foreach`
- Do `strip_tags` each element and check length
- If length is 0, then do not print.