# Regex to replace series of whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace a tag inside HTML string if the tag only contain empty spaces.

I've following HTML string:

```
<p>Data</p>

 <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>  I want this to be replaced with <p><br></p>`
```

I've made this regex:

```
  /<p>(&nbsp;)*<\/p>/g
```

But this is failing when we have spaces in between or in starting pf `p` tag `&nbsp;` like

```
<p> &nbsp;      &nbsp; </p> // replacable
<p>&nbsp;&npsp; &nbsp; </p> // replacable
<p>&nbsp;    &nbsp;  hey </p> // not-replacable as it contains data
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to want `<p>(?:\s|&nbsp;)*<\/p>`

Comment: Thanks man @WiktorStribiżew you saved me twice :)

Comment: This is actually from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950175/3832970).

Comment: gotcha @WiktorStribiżew. Even then thanks. I googled about this issue but couldn't reached to this post.